# Finding repeated statements in a document

Tags: algorithm, sequence, text-analysis

Suppose there is a document which contain a number of repeating statements (like Log messages). eg ( a b d c e a d) where think each alphabet as a sentence.

We need to find out all possible unique sequence and its count. eg ( abd = 1 . bd = 1. ad = 1 etc etc.)

We are given the minimum and maximum of the number of sentences that can be in a sequence.

How can we do it most efficiently, in terms of both space and time?

I tried coding it as a tree problem in two steps (finding possible combination and then the count). I looked at Suffix Tree but space complexity may be large, considering we are dealing with sentences

Comment: show your "attempts" and were in particular you are stuck.

Comment: When you consider a line split in pieces different from one line, you can simplify by testing chunks with a fixed number of lines.
And when the first (set of) line(s) is already unique, you can skip any longer combination as well. Was my answer suffficient?

Comment: Hi Rishabh, was my solution something useful?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following thing:

1. Map all sentences to integers(using a hash map).
2. Build a suffix tree/suffix array/suffix automaton for the resulting array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

For all possible strings (one line/2 lines/.../all lines) calculate and count the hash.

Pseudo-code:

```
for (firstline=0; firstline< N_LINES; firstline++) {
   for (lastline=firstline; lastline<N_LINES; lastline++) {
      newhash=calculateHash(firstline until lastline);
      count_and_store(newhash)
   }
}
```

Edit: Don't use Brute force

A solution for skipping checks would be checking 1 line/2 lines hashes first.
You start checking with 1 logline. You only need to continue checking for more loglines when the substring of the first logline(s) not are unique.

```
    Boolean array array_lineNumber [N_LINES]; # Init this array all values false 
    Hashtype array substringCalculatedHash [N_LINES]; # Do not recalculate hash when checking
Hashtype array fullstringCalculatedHash [N_LINES]; # Store hashes for current length

    function checkRepeatedHashSubstring(startline) {
       if (numberOfHashesEqualTo(substringCalculatedHash[startline])>1) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    }

    for (numberlines=1; numberlines<N_lines; numberlines++)
    {
        for (firstline=0; firstline< N_LINES; firstline++) {
           if (array_lineNumber_unique[firstline]==true) {
              # Unique log combination since the substring was unique as well.
              # Just fill the hashmap for the current number_lines with the unique hash calculated for numberlines-1
              fullstringCalculatedHash[firstline]=substringCalculatedHash[firstline];
              continue; # Skip checking.
           }
           if (checkRepeatedHashSubstring(firstline) {
              newhash=calculateHash(firstline until lastline);
              fullstringCalculatedHash[firstline]=newhash;
           } else {
              # substring was unique, so complete string is unique as well
               fullstringCalculatedHash[firstline]=substringCalculatedHash[firstline];
              array_lineNumber_unique[firstline]=true;
           }
           count_and_logSubstringsCalculated(copy_fullstringCalculatedHash);
           copy_fullstringCalculatedHash_to_substringCalculatedHash();  
        }
}
```

Comment: It is O(n^2 * time_for_calculateHash). It seems to me that the author of this question wants a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: @ILoveCoding You are right. I edited my brute-force solution into one that skips calculating hashes as soon as it is known that the subset of loglines aren't unique. When all lines are unique, it will be O(n * (some more calculations/actions)).